# In the context of ruby modules, what is the difference between a self.method and a regular method?

Tags: ruby

So, from what I understand, in a class, a `self.method` is like a class method, whereas a regular `method` is like an instance method.  But, as you can't instantiate a module, why would I use one over the other?  What is the difference between these two in a module?

Comment: The purpose of a module is to either extend or include methods in other classes to provide multiple inheritances in ruby. Hence instance_method and class_method in the module serve the same purpose as we intend to do in class.

Comment: I don't understand.  I thought that classes inherit from classes.  What do you mean by extend or include methods in other classes?

Comment: Modules are the primary object type. See my http://www.apeth.com/rubyIntro/justenoughruby.html for a tutorial that takes this approach

Answer (score 1):

> So, from what I understand, in a class, a `self.method` is like a class method, whereas a regular `method` is like an instance method.

That is not true. Ruby only has one single kind of method: instance methods. So, what you call a "regular method" is not "like" an instance method, it *is* an instance method. And there are no class methods in Ruby, *every method* is an instance method.

There are two ways to define a method in Ruby: with an explicit definee (`def foo.bar`) and without (`def bar`, which is then using the [*default definee*](https://blog.yugui.jp/entry/846)).

In the first case, it is easy to know where a method will be defined: if you say `def foo.bar`, the method will become an instance method of `foo`'s singleton class, always.

If you say `def bar`, the method becomes an instance method of the *default definee*, which usually, but not always, is the *closest lexically enclosing module definition body*. The most notable exception is a method that is defined directly in a script body, in this case, there is no lexically enclosing module definition, and the default definee is `Object` instead. In fact, there is even another twist: the method will be implicitly defined as `private` as well.

So, in your case, the first method will become an instance method of the singleton class of `self` (and inside a module definition body, `self` is the module itself), the second method will become an instance method of the module.

> But, as you can't instantiate a module,

Ruby has a feature called *inheritance*. While it is true that you can directly instantiate a module, you *can* instantiate a class that inherits from a module. In fact, since the `Object` class inherits from the `Kernel` module (which has instance methods like `Kernel#puts` or `Kernel#require`, which may have used once or twice), and almost every class directly or indirectly inherits from `Object`, it is highly likely that you will have in your Ruby programming already have instantiated an indirect instance of a module and used a module's instance methods.

`Enumerable` is another important module in Ruby that contains methods like `map`, `select`, etc. that both `Array` and `Hash` inherit from.

> why would I use one over the other?

There's really not much to it: you'd use an instance method, if you want to … well use an instance method, i.e. want to have a method that has privileged access to the internal representation of `self` across many different instances of the same module.

You would use a method of the singleton class, if you want the method to be only available for that single object.

Comment: _While it is true that you can directly instantiate a module,_  I think you mean can't here.

Comment: So would you say that using `self.method` is so that when  inheriting from a module, it wouldn't get pulled into the class, where a `method` would?  In OO terms, would you also say that a module would be akin to an abstract class, in that you cannot instantiate it?

Answer (score 0):

There is one and only one reason for having module methods: to invoke those methods on the module in which they defined (using `self`: `def self.my_method...`). An example of this is Ruby's built-in [Math](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Math.html) module. All methods in this module are module methods. These methods are all invoked with `Math` as their explicit receiver (e.g., `Math.sqrt(2.5)`). In effect, they are used like functions in non-OO languages.

When you `include`, `prepend` or `extend` a module from a class, any module methods are simply ignored.

Comment: Actually, all methods in `Math` exist twice: once as instance methods of `Math`, once as instance methods of `Math`'s singleton class. That way, you can either use them like `Math.sin(0)` or like `include Math; sin(0)`. There is a built-in method `Module#module_function` which allows you to easily create such duplicated methods.

Comment: Jörg, I was not aware of that, as I've not see it in the doc for [Math](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Math.html). I noticed that when `Math` is included by a class the instance methods are private, consistent with your reference to `sin(0)`. Thanks for the observation. Are you aware of other built-in modules where that is done? I understand this does not bear on my explanation, just on my example of the `Math` module.

Comment: I believe it is specific to `Math`, at least in the core library, since it is the only "utility module" of that kind. `Kernel` *looks* like it works that way, because you can call `Kernel.puts`, but that's because `Kernel` is an instance of itself, not because those are module functions.

Comment: And yes, `module_function` makes the methods `private`, I believe. They are not intended to be used with a receiver, they are intended to be used as "global procedures" (like `puts`, which is also private). The intention is essentially to allow you to write mathy scripts without having to type `Math.` all over again.

Comment: Jörg, I don't dispute that all methods are instance methods, but many Rubyists, myself included, commonly refer to instance methods of a class' singleton class as "class methods" simply as shorthand. It's just less of a mouthful.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this (timely) article helpful in understanding the Ruby object model and how methods are “looked up”: https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-method-lookup/